# I have problem with using the *mul* operator to multiply varibales

Tags: python-3.x, list, operators, multiplication

I splited and converted string  into **int** and i want use the `mul`
operator to multiply directly. But they is an error when printing the last output.

```
from operator import mul 
# mulptiply user input
input_string = input("Enter numbers for summing :")

print("/n")
user_list = input_string.split()
print('list:', user_list)

# for loop to iterate 
for x in range(len(user_list)):
        user_list[x] = int(user_list[x]
                           
 # calc the mul of the list   
print("Multiplication of list =", mul(user_list))
```

Comment: `mul` is a binary operator, it takes exactly 2 arguments. You can't multiple every element of a list using a single `mul`. Why don't you simply multiply them within the `for` loop you use to convert them to `int`s? Also next time post the error message with full traceback instead of only saying "there is an error".

Comment: got it. thanks @Selcuk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mul` function takes 2 arguments at a time and returns their product. If you want to use `mul` to calculate the product of a list of numbers you can use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) to apply the function cumulatively to every list item for an aggregated result:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul

user_list = [2, 3, 4]
print(reduce(mul, user_list)) # outputs 24
```

Beginning in Python 3.8 you can also use [`math.prod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.prod) to calculate the product of a list of numbers directly.